# How to omit a row in calculations?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following data (the first column is Excel's row number, the actual values of column `A` are `10`, `10`, ...)

```
   A
1 10
2 10
3 15
4 27
```

When making a `SUM(A:A)` all figures in the column are taken into account.

**Is there a way to temporarily disable a row?** (say, row `3` above)

I could delete it but then the analysis gets complicated when some rows need to be taken into accounts, and some other not - different depending on the analysis.

I could create a column which would be a flag and build a formula around this - it seems awkward, though.

I am looking for something like PowerPoint *Hide* function: the slide exists but is not part of the presentation. Hiding in Excel does not work that: the row is not visible but still used in calculations.

Comment: is it always row 3 you want to omit, is it always just a single row ?

Comment: You could try shifting that row to the right, leaving a blank cell in `A3`, though I don't know what what this will do to the rest of the spreadsheet calculations. A more complicated edit is to change `15` to `=Z(15)`, where `Z()` is a VBA function which returns zero, regardless of the passed parameter. If you want to include again, make `Z()` return its parameter. This allows you easily to include or exclude several cells at will.

Answer (score 1):

If you format your data as a table and sum below values when you hide the rows the values will be removed from the total.  You an then reference this total cell elsewhere if you need it to show somewhere else.  You can even hide this total cell at the bottom of the data.

[image: Table Formatted Information]

I hope this will provide you with some ideas to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try stacking sums: =SUM(G9:G10)+SUM(G12:G99)
Or you could set the color of the fields you want to exclude, then build a macro that fetches the color: cell.interior.color and then builds a new sum. That will require up front work and I'm not sure if it can be done, but it might be worth a shot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382561/excel-formula-to-get-cell-color

Answer (score 0):

You could do `=SUM(A:A)-A3` - while it doesn't ignore it in the calculation, it excludes it from the final answer.